# Improve performances of division Vivado HLS

Tags: c, optimization, vivado, vivado-hls

I'm computing the incremental mean of my input data (which is an array of 6 elements, so i'll end up with 6 means).

This is the code I'm using everytime a new input array is available (obviously I update the number of samples ecc...):

```
computing_mean:for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
       temp_mean[i]=temp_mean[i] + (input[i]-temp_mean[i])/number_of_samples;
       //Possible optimization?
       //temp_mean[i]=temp_mean[i] + divide(input[i]-temp_mean[i],number_of_samples);

}
```

Where all the data in the code are arrays or single number of the following type:

```
typedef ap_fixed <36,24,AP_RND_CONV,AP_SAT> decimalNumber;
```

From my synthesis report this loop hase 324 latency and 54 iteration latency, caused mainly by the division operation.

Are there any ways I can improve the speed of the division? I tried using hls_math and the divide function, but it doesn't seem to work with my type of data.

**EDIT 1**: I'm including my performance profiler inside vivado HLS. I'll add a self-contained reproducible code later with another edit.
As you can see, the majority of the time is spent in SDIV
[image]

Comment: Can you vectorize it?

Comment: Do you mean removing the cycle and perform operation on the vectors? I don't know if it's possible in ANSII C.

Comment: ANSI C? Is this some legacy codebase? Vectorizing is just taking advantage of SIMD instructions, it's not a function of C itself.

Comment: Oh sorry, i'm new to this world (Vivado HLS). How would you achieve that?

Comment: If you're asking "is there a magic wand I can wave over this code and make it faster" the answer is no. If you're asking "is there a way to make this code faster by reworking it" the answer is long and complicated, but yes. The difficult, but relatively simplest approach is to see if you can vectorize this with SIMD instructions. The more difficult but possibly better approach is to see if you can dump all of this onto a GPU and write it as a kernel function.

Comment: That being said, I'm not sure that doing six division operations is really the problem here. This is part of a larger problem and may be only a tiny factor in what's causing the performance issue.

Comment: The question is the second one. I'm working inside Vivado HLS and I was wondering if it was possible to improve the performances of the division operation. Like using some pragmas or something else (which is unknown to me at the moment) to speed up the computation. I can provide further details if needed, like my synthesis report

Comment: For example, I saw that hls_math contains optimized arithmetic functions, but nfortunately divide is not available (at least this is what I saw, maybe i'm wrong) for the type of data I specified

Comment: You're asking for a magic wand. It does not exist. Why do you think this particular line is the problem? Do you you have a profiler report?

Comment: Yes, I have my synthesis report with the timing and the division operation is taking quite a lot of time. I can add it if needed

Comment: I really don't think that will help. This is a problem you'll need to dig in a lot more on your own since you have access to the rest of the code and we don't unless you can make a minimal, self-contained example we can profile that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I'll write a reproducible code, just wait a moment

Comment: What units are those numbers in for the latency chart? Clock cycles or µs?

Comment: They're clock cycles

Comment: That might seem like a lot of time, but it's really not. Division is computationally more expensive, it's true, but it won't be cripplingly expensive in most cases. If you have a performance problem it's probably do do with one of: cache misses, data layout issues, poor structure design, or a fundamentally ineffective algorithm.

Comment: I was wondering if there was any way to optimize the division computation since it's the bottleneck of my whole system (I don't have any real problem, it works fine, but the division is the operation that takes the most in my whole system). Everything else has good perfomances (I could optimize even more and I know what to do) but the major problem is the division computation

Comment: Other than trigonometric functions like `sin()` and `cos()`, or things like `sqrt()`, division will always be the most painful. There are occasions where you can skip division and do bit-shifting instead, *if* you're working with integer data *and* the number you're dividing by is a power of 2, but that's about it.

Comment: You can add your last comment as answer and i'll accept it

Comment: Is this `int`, `float`, `double` or what?

Comment: I wrote it in the question, all the data in the question is decimalNumber, defined in the typedef I wrote.

Comment: Can you translate that into C? If this is some wonky fixed-point math type this could be the issue. SIMD can't really deal with that.

Comment: It's a Vivado HLS library. Basically defines a fixed point number of 36 bits with 24 bits for the integer part.

Comment: Guess you're stuck with what you've got then. I proposed a possible "hack" solution in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than trigonometric functions like `sin()` (`FSIN` = ~50-170 cycles) and `cos()` (`FCOS` = ~50-120 cycles), or things like `sqrt()` (`FSQRT` = ~22 cycles), division will always be the most painful.

`FDIV` is 15 cycles. `FADD` and `FMUL` are both 5.

There are occasions where you can skip division and do bit-shifting instead, if you're working with integer data and the number you're dividing by is a power of 2, but that's about it.

You can look up the approximate CPU cycle cost of any given instruction in [tables like this](https://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf). `FDIV` is an example of an expensive one.

That being said, one thing you could try is to compute the division factor in advance, then apply it using multiplication instead:

```
double inverse_n = 1 / number_of_samples;

temp_mean[i]=temp_mean[i] + (input[i]-temp_mean[i]) * inverse_n;
```

I'm not sure that's saving a whole lot, but if you really do need to shave off cycles, it's worth a shot.